# What's wrong with my Callback?

Tags: javascript, callback

I'm trying to learn callbacks and wondered what I've done wrong here as I was expecting to get a message after 4 secs:

> I've tried to fire but one of the funcs isn't finished yet

followed by another message after 8 secs:

> I waited for the two functions to finish and now I've fired

Instead I just get:

> I waited for the two functions to finish and now I've fired

twice, both after 4 secs and again after 8 secs.

```
var cbvarone = false;
var cbvartwo = false;

var whenOthersFinished = function() {
    if (cbvartwo && cbvartwo) {
    console.log("I waited for the two functions to finish and now I've fired");
    }
    else {
    console.log("I've tried to fire but one of the funcs isn't finished yet");
    }
};

var firstFunc = function(cb) {
    setTimeout(function(){cbvarone = true; cb();}, 8000);
};

var secondFunc = function(cb) {
    setTimeout(function(){cbvartwo = true; cb();}, 4000);
};

firstFunc(whenOthersFinished);
secondFunc(whenOthersFinished);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your function:

```
var whenOthersFinished = function() {
    if (cbvartwo && cbvartwo) {
    console.log("I waited for the two functions to finish and now I've fired");
    }
    else {
    console.log("I've tried to fire but one of the funcs isn't finished yet");
    }
};
```

your if statement is:

```
if (cbvartwo && cbvartwo)
```

Change that to:

```
if (cbvarone && cbvartwo)
```

All should be fine. I verified and your code works as expected with the changes

Answer (score 2):

You have:

`if (cbvartwo && cbvartwo) {`

I think you meant to do:

`if (cbvarone && cbvartwo) {`

Answer (score 1):

```
if (cbvartwo && cbvartwo) {
```

should probably be

```
if (cbvarone && cbvartwo) {
```